# How to stop excel operating while macro is running?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have a macro that lasts 10 minutes. For example, I activate the workbook, when somebody clicks it changes wrong ranges from excels. Please don't say "don't use select or activate". I know but from this point it is impossible to change since I have a long macro that lasts 10 minutes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Don't use select or activate" is the correct answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is not allowing us to answer the question correctly ;-)

Comment: Just like the answer to your last Q.  Take the pain now, you'll thanks us later.

Comment: but to take the pain, you need to define every range. It will be much more slower than using select.

Comment: Question doesn't show the minimal amount of information we need to be able to help with your problem and there is not a specific question. Please provide block of code you think your problem is in and refine what you want to solve.

Comment: It is not about the code, it is a general thing. While macro is working, when someone presses the excel sheet, the macro is continueuing to work on the clicked excel workbook since you change the activeworkbook. So even if you do not use select, it will give the same error. I only want to "lock" the excel. By meaning that, even if a person clicks the excel, the excel shouldn't recognize it until macro said so.

Comment: "when someone presses the excel sheet, the macro is continueuing to work on the clicked excel workbook since you change the activeworkbook".  You can get around this problem by correctly qualifying each of your ranges, and avoiding the use of `Select` and `Activate`.  You shouldn't rely on `ActiveWorkbook` or `ActiveSheet` being what they were when you start the macro running, unless you are the only person who is going to use the macro, and you refrain from touching your keyboard / mouse while the macro is running.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit ctrl+break / ctrl/pause and it exits my macro and says "Code execution has been interrupted".

Comment: Someone care to explain why the downed my answer?